# how i do design in React Native like image

Tags: android, react-native

i'm new in React Native and i don't know how do this:

[image]

How i do for create a component similar to image,
My code is this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function SeccionA({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.contenedor}>
            <View style={styles.listado} >
                <View style={styles.listadoItem}>
                    <Text>BVCC</Text>               
                    <Text>15.709</Text>
                    <Text>2.65</Text>
                    <Text>2%</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.listadoItem}>
                    <Text>IBC</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.listadoItem}>
                    <Text>Industrial</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.listadoItem}>
                    <Text>Financiero</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.listadoItem}>
                    <Text></Text>
                </View>
            </View>        
        </View>
    );
}
   
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contenedor: {
        marginHorizontal: 10
    },
    listado: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
      },
      listadoItem: {
        flexBasis: '49%',
        paddingHorizontal: 30
      },    
});
```

This is call by initial page like component,

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a ScrollView with props horizaontal and put the text into the TouchableHighlight object

```
<ScrollView
                horizontal
            >
              <TouchableHighlight 
                onPress={ () => { 
                  setWhatTab(0);
                }
              }
              >
                <Image 
                  source={require('../img/btnTransadas.png')}
                  style={{padding: 10, height: 27}}
                />
              </TouchableHighlight>                                
              <TouchableHighlight 
                style={styles.btnCotizar}
                onPress={ () => {
                    setWhatTab(1);
                  }
                }
              >
              <Image 
                  source={require('../img/btnBajando.png')}
                  style={{padding: 10, height: 27}}
                />
              </TouchableHighlight>                                
              <TouchableHighlight 
                style={styles.btnCotizar}
                  onPress={ () => {
                    setWhatTab(2);
                  }
                } 
              >
                <Image 
                  source={require('../img/btnSubiendo.png')}
                  style={{padding: 10, height: 27}}
                />
              </TouchableHighlight>                                
              <TouchableHighlight 
                style={styles.btnCotizar}
                  onPress={ () => {
                    setWhatTab(3);
                  }
                } 
              >
                <Image 
                  source={require('../img/btnCotizaciones.png')}
                  style={{padding: 10, height: 27}}
                />
              </TouchableHighlight>                                
            </ScrollView>
```